# What is the max memo length in a transaction? And what is the cost?

Tags: transactions, memo

```
solana transfer --with-memo <MEMO> <RECIPIENT_ADDRESS> <AMOUNT>
```

What is the max length in a memo transaction? And does the fee go up in proportion to how long your memo is? If so by how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Memo Program docs](https://spl.solana.com/memo) and [github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/memo):

> As of v1.5.1, an unsigned instruction can support single-byte UTF-8 of up to 566 bytes. An instruction with a simple memo of 32 bytes can support up to 12 signers.

The message itself will be both on-chain (since the instruction of the Memo Program is an instruction (i.e. a "call" of an on-chain Program), as is as such part of the ledger.

In addition, the Memo Program will also write the message to the "log", a simple text file that every validator and RPC node generates, and that can be read from RPC nodes using e.g. `getSignaturesForAddress` from the [@solana/web3.js library](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html), see [docs](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getSignaturesForAddress).